# Tell me what I am

Tags: riddle

> I build up castles and tear down mountains
>   I blind some men and help others to see.
>   I may be quick, though many box me in.

What am I?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answer is

> Sand

I build up castles and tear down mountains

> Sand is used to build sand castles and sand can erode mountains

I blind some men and help others to see

> Sand storms can blind people and sand is used to make glass for eye glasses

I may be quick, tho many box me in.

> Quick sand, sand box

Answer (score 0):

I build up castles and tear down mountains

> Stone is used in building castles and also tear mountains.

I blind some men and help others to see.

> Stone dust most harmful to eyes and stone such as tiger stone release fear,anxiety, stimulates taking actions and helps to make decisions with understanding.  So in a way helping clear vision.

I may be quick, though many box me in.

> Rolling stones are fast but they are kept in box in household for decoration.

What am I?

> Stone.